# Hanging build in Jenkins/Hudson.Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jenkins

when I start a build on Jenkins(Hudson back then) it goes all well , but at the end , just before the end , it starts hanging. After checking the thread dump I found it always hangs on the same thread :

```
 Id=81 Group=main WAITING on com.trilead.ssh2.channel.Channel@76def13f
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on com.trilead.ssh2.channel.Channel@76def13f
```

Any suggestions on fixing that issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's waiting for some network resource...

Comment: What version of Jenkins/Hudson are you running?

Comment: The version shown is 1.590

Comment: Please attach full output of `jstack -l $PID`. Edit: From your Jenkins master - not slave. You have not specified which one you are looking at in the question.